# Change the color of the nav tag when scroll

Tags: jquery

I want to change the color of the `<a>` element of the nav when I scroll down.

Here the example of where I take the original jquery code https://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-fixed-navigation/

I change this code for my project but it doesn't work, what's wrong ?

```
var contentSections = $('.section');
var navigationItems = $('.nav a');

updateNavigation();
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    updateNavigation();
});

function updateNavigation() {
    contentSections.each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        var activeSection = $('.nav a[href="#'+$this.attr("class")+'"]');
        if ( ( $this.offset().top - $(window).height()/2 < $(window).scrollTop() ) && ( $this.offset().top + $this.height() - $(window).height()/2 > $(window).scrollTop() ) ) {
            navigationItems.eq(activeSection).addClass('selected');
        }else {
            navigationItems.eq(activeSection).removeClass('selected');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/esten/pen/GjAxRX

There are a few issues. Your `activeSection` selector is returning all of the class names on that element, not solely the section identifier you want. I changed that selector to look for `.attr('id')` rather than class (I had to add an ID to the portfolio section, and I changed the id of the portfolio header to accommodate  this).

```
var contentSections = $('.section');
var navigationItems = $('.nav a');

updateNavigation();
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  updateNavigation();
});

function updateNavigation() {

  contentSections.each(function() {
    //console.log($(this));
    $this = $(this);
    var activeSection = $('.nav a[href="#' + $this.attr("id") + '"]');

    if (($this.offset().top - $(window).height() / 2 < $(window).scrollTop()) && ($this.offset().top + $this.height($(window).height() / 2 >     $(window).scrollTop())) {
      activeSection.addClass('selected');
    } else {
      activeSection.removeClass('selected');
    }
  });
}
```

Also, since `activeSection` is selecting your anchor tag element, you just need to add the class directly to that element.

This should get the `selected` class applied to the nav elements, then you need to be more specific with your CSS selector:

```
.nav a.selected {
  color: blue
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, it's almost perfect, only home and contact doesn't work, i think for this piece of code:

if (($this.offset().top - $(window).height() / 2 < $(window).scrollTop()) && ($this.offset().top + $this.height($(window).height() / 2 >     $(window).scrollTop())) {

How can i set the height of the window that the home and contact works ?

I made an update of the repo ;)

Comment: I've added some comments to the codepen. Check that out again. Basically, the code is looking for when the element hits the middle of the window. You'll want to adjust that "if" statement how you want it.

I'll look again tomorrow.